# Unity3d Xcode Mprotect remapping failed error. What it is and how to fix?

Tags: ios, xcode, multithreading, unity-game-engine, mono

I'm stumped with an error I found and from my searches, only a few have also received it a long time ago and I'm not quite sure if / how a solution was achieved.

The error I'm getting in xcode is

```
Mprotect failed at 0xed50000 (length 212992) with errno 12
Mprotect remapping failed
```

The game works fine in the editor and all other platforms. This error is iOS specific and happens every session that goes past the login process (loads another scene) for > 10 seconds. The exact time is inconsistent. *I say inconsistently because it doesn't seem to happen right after an interaction. My game does download data and images so my hunch (and a lousy hunch at that) is threading / wait time is the cause of the inconsistently.*

Here's some of my search results

- http://forum.unity3d.com/threads/mprotect-failed-at-0x51fa000.15858/
- this is from all the way back from 2008 and it looked like it was a
  hotfixed by Unity
- http://forum.unity3d.com/threads/mprotect-remapping-failed.15443/
  this is more of the same but a Unity dev did mention:

  > Workaround: don't allocate mono objects too frequently, reuse them if 
  >   possible (this would also improve your performance).
- This is a little embarrassing since I'm a self taught Unity user but
  what exactly does that mean and can I apply it to my problem?

My system info:

Currently on Unity 5.3 but has been happening since 5.2 Xcode is version 7.2 but has been happening since 7.0 I think My game is 2d, it uses NGUI, it downloads data and images from the internet.

Thank you so much for your read and time. Hope you can help!